# Read first only record from json file using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have json file having content like this :

```
[{
    "name" : "Mak",
    "registration_code" : "Registration code",
    "date" :"date",
    "time" : "time",
    "file_data" :{
        "Feature_0" : "0,0.956222737454317,"
    }
  },
  {
    "name" : "Andy",
    "date" :"date",
    "time" : "time",
    "file_data" :{
        "Feature_0" : "0,0.956222737454317, "
    }
  }]
```

Right now to read first record i am using file_get_contents get complete data and then parsing into array.
I want to fetch only first record without getting whole file content in memory using php. Is there any way to do this ?

Many Thanks, M.

Comment: JSON would not be an appropriate storage method for this. Consider CSV instead, which can be read line-by-line.

Comment: *"I want to fetch only first record without getting whole file content in memory"* -- there is no such thing as "first record" in JSON. JSON is a text representation of some data structure. You have to read all the text from the file, parse it to restore the data structure and only after that you can extract pieces from it. There is no other way using JSON. Maybe it is not the most appropriate storage format for your needs.

Comment: but data might nested upto any level in json file but in csv i do not have any idea how to manage that

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack but if you know the JSON structure. Anyway `},` may not occur in the first record.

```
$first = explode("},", $json_string, 2)[0];
$first .= "}]";
$obj = json_decode($first)[0];
```

If you do not want to read the whole JSON file you could do something like this (adjust to your needs!):

```
         $content = "";
         $handle = fopen("json.file", "r"); if ($handle) {
         while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

                // with nested objects you have to count the occurrences of { and make sure it is the closer for the first object
                if (strpos($line, '},') !== false) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    $content .= $line;
                }
           }

           fclose($handle); 
        }  // proceed only with the lines read ...
        $content .= "}]";
        $obj = json_decode($content)[0];
```

Anway everything which I just suggested here **is usually not recommendable (in 99% of the use cases)**. Maybe you have to adapt this code a bit and also it will not work for minified JSON.

Better you parse the whole file and go ahead.

Comment: I know json structure very well, But i want to do it without having all data into $string variable.

Comment: still you are storing complete json data into $json_string variable ?

Comment: Not with the updated answer. However this ONLY works if the JSON is not minified and if there is no space after } . Otherwise you have to adjust the code. For minified files you may use http://php.net/manual/de/function.fread.php.

Comment: Nice try bro.. Thanks